# php error_log ceases upon function return

Tags: php, debugging

I've got a situation where I'm trying to debug Drupal's php.  Not being a php hacker, I'm using error_log a lot.  I've gotten it to the point that error_log on exit to function drupal_bootstrap indicates bootstrapping is done.  Its the last statement before the closing '}'.

However, the error_log immediately following the call to drupal_boostrap never shows up in the website's error_log file.

I've gone so far as to place a:

```
setbuf(stderr, NULL);
```

right before the error_log call.  No effect.

Just as strange is the fact that
    exit();
is called during phase 5 of the bootstrap, yet the error_log indicating that bootstrapping is done is executed.

Comment: You'd be a happier man using [**FirePHP**](http://www.firephp.org/).

Comment: Have you got error reporting turned on? Perhaps the `drupal_bootstrap()` is erroring out before your `error_log()` can be called. Place these at the very beginning of your PHP `ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', true);`

Comment: ini_set('error_reporting',E_ALL);
has no effect.  Nor would one expect, in this particular situation, for it to have any effect.  The "error_log" function is very low level and the only thing executing between the "error_log" that shows up and the "error_log" that doesn't show up is the return from the function (ie: '}' occurs immediately after the call to "error_log" that worked).